# make physics body jump in cocos2d-Box2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I am a newbie to the gaming world i am stuccoed to make a physics body jump..
here is how i defined the body

```
Cycle = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Panda.png"];
        [self addChild:Cycle z:3];

    // Create a world
    b2Vec2 gravity = b2Vec2(0.0f, -8.0f);
    world = new b2World(gravity);

    // Create edges around the entire screen
    b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
    groundBodyDef.position.Set(0,0);

    b2Body *groundBody = world->CreateBody(&groundBodyDef);
    b2EdgeShape groundEdge;
    b2FixtureDef boxShapeDef;
    boxShapeDef.shape = &groundEdge;

    //wall definitions
    groundEdge.Set(b2Vec2(0,0), b2Vec2(screenSize.width/PTM_RATIO, 0));
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);

    groundEdge.Set(b2Vec2(0,0), b2Vec2(0,screenSize.height/PTM_RATIO));
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);

    groundEdge.Set(b2Vec2(0, screenSize.height/PTM_RATIO),
                   b2Vec2(screenSize.width/PTM_RATIO, screenSize.height/PTM_RATIO));
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);

    groundEdge.Set(b2Vec2(screenSize.width/PTM_RATIO, screenSize.height/PTM_RATIO),
                   b2Vec2(screenSize.width/PTM_RATIO, 0));
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);

    // Create ball body and shape
    b2BodyDef ballBodyDef;
    ballBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    ballBodyDef.position.Set(300/PTM_RATIO,100/PTM_RATIO);
    ballBodyDef.userData = Cycle;
    body = world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDef);


    b2PolygonShape dynamicBox;
    dynamicBox.SetAsBox(.5f, .5f);//These are mid points for our 1m box

    // Define the dynamic body fixture.
    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &dynamicBox;
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;
    body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
```

and in touches began i am applying linear impulse as

```
b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(30, 30);
body-> ApplyLinearImpulse(body->GetPosition(),force);
```

so can any body tell me what am i doing wrong..
thanks in advance..

Comment: what do you want to achieve, what do you have now? add some details others to understand your problem.

Comment: jump = one-time upward force. If it doesn't jump try changing force.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D i did this with this one // Working in horizontal direction
    b2Vec2 locationWorld;
    locationWorld = b2Vec2(0.0f,8.0f);
    double Force= body->GetMass();
    body->ApplyLinearImpulse(Force*locationWorld, body->GetWorldCenter());   but the force is applied in horizontal direction i want it in vertical....

Comment: @LearnCocos2D and if i change the coordinates the body moves randomly along whole screen please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of that article by iForce2D. This should explain quite a bit.

[iForce2D - Box2D Tutorials - Jumping](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/jumping)

Answer (score 0):

Remember position of your sprite and body (bodyDef) should be same, In this code the position of your sprite is not shown. And it seems that this is causing the problem. After this use the   setLinearVelicoty() Or ApplylinearForce() methods instead of using ApplyLinearImpulse().

Answer (score 0):

You make can jump by changing the Y velocity of your body like this

```
    b2Vec2 velocity = body_->GetLinearVelocity();
    velocity.y = 20;
    velocity.x = 0;//upwards - don't change x velocity
    body_->SetLinearVelocity( velocity );
```